# Vue.js/webpack SPA: point all output files to CDN, except .html?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, single-page-application

for my single page app, I would like to deploy all linked files (JS, CSS, JPG, WOFF, etc) from a CDN at `https://cdn.example.com`. I can change `publicPath` in the webpack config and this sets all the links correctly. However, it also makes the Vue Router think the server root is `cdn.example.com` instead of just simply `example.com`. Thus, any links off the home page handled by Vue Router point to a cdn page which doesn't exist.

Ideally:

- `index.html` (which handles all the Vue routes) served from web server at `https://example.com` ( `https://example.com/contact-us` , `https://example.com/about-us` etc)
- Everything else served from CDN servers at `https://cdn.example.com`

Possible? Thank you.

Comment: I assume you're looking for [webpack-cdn-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-cdn-plugin)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I believe that plugin allows you to pull known, external libraries from a CDN, like if you wanted to link to jQuery or something. I am talking about the JS, CSS, etc that webpack itself creates, with filenames like `6.fx147e2e.css` and `runtime.b89y8ya.js`

Answer (score 0):

My fundamental misunderstanding was that a CDN network was "dumb" in that it just served static files as-is and had no capacity to perform features of a web server such as forcing SSL and handling server redirects, which are especially important for single-page apps. I believed that the root `index.html` still needed to be served from a traditional, non-CDN web server.

So the answer doesn't lie within webpack, the answer is to find a solid CDN that handle the necessary features and serve the entire site from there.

Comment: how did you proceed? which CDN did you use and did you use some sort of a gateway (nginx) to route requests to CDN-hosted static files and your backend/API instance?

Comment: @sbay Since we're building a *single-page* app, we need the routes www.example.com/page1 and www.example.com/page2 to actually be served by www.example.com/index.html . I mistakenly believed CDNs were unable to manage this redirection, actually, most handle this quite easily. Setting it up will differ by platform, but it should be part of the CDN's site config settings. The CDN should also be able to handle things like redirecting all http traffic to https, modifying headers, setting different cache times for different assets and other features that may be necessary.

Comment: @sbay  As far as the backend/API, it is probably best to create an entirely different domain, say api.example.com, and serve it from a live node/python/Java/php/etc server (not a CDN)